# paypal returnUrl loses sessionId on return

Tags: django, paypal

I have implemented a paypal Express Checkout for digital goods on my django application.

Everything works perfectly on chrome and firefox. however on IE10 , everything works until paypal calls my return_url. for some reason it lose its session and direct me to a login-page because of how django registartion works. ( U use required_login decorator)

Looking deeper, I figured that on the return_url there is no sessionId cookie. I have no clue how any why does it happens, because it does work on firefox and chrome..

Answer (score 0):

You can find the playpal integration with django [here](http://od-eon.com/blogs/nai/django-paypal-step-step-integration/)

Comment: I wrote that my implementation work perfectly but not working only on ie10.. a basic paypal integration with django-paypal doesn't help here I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I solved the problem. The reason seems to be that on IE cookies are deleted if a site redirect you back and you have no P3P settings.

I integrate django-p3p and problem seems to be solved.